# Using Android.os.* classes for OTA updates

Tags: android

So, i'm developing app which need OTA updates functionality. And i found this sample https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bootable/recovery/+/master/updater_sample

But this code using some classes, for example android.os.UpdateEngine

I cannot find it in my library. What i should to do?